# Odometry Problem

Tags: navigation, odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello folks,

I am making an odometry node for an omnidirectional robot using mechanum wheels. I've followed the tutorial on the ROS wiki, making changes as needed for my particular robot. The problem is that while I get values for the twist values, I get NaN for the pose. You can find the code [here](https://github.com/Icehawk101/ax2550/blob/master/src/omni_odom.cpp). I've tried debugging my code, and I get values up to the delta_th line. When I look at x, y, and th though that is where I get NaN. The variable types match, so that shouldn't be a problem. When I try adding a constant (1 and 1.0) instead of the delta then I do get a value returned. I am unsure why this is. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189689/odometry-problem/) by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2014-08-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-08-11**:
did you if dt_front, dt_rear are getting zero ?

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2014-08-11**:
I checked that, they are getting values.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-08-11**:
Why not just add a lot of ROS_INFO_STREAM statements before and after every calculation until you find the culprit? Also, just from a "good practices" standpoint, you really should initialize the variables in lines 6 - 11 in your main function (before you subscribe to any callbacks).

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2014-08-11**:
dt_front: 0.999999
dt_rear: 0.999926
v_w1: 0.122492
v_w2: -0.119761
v_w3: 0.119651
v_w4: -0.117248
avg_dt: 0.999963
vx before: 0.000160434
vx after: 0.000160434
vy before: -0.0149735
vy after: -0.0149735
vth before:  -2.32918e-05
vth after:  -2.32918e-05

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2014-08-11**:
delta_x: 0.000160428
delta_y: -0.0149729
delta_th: -2.32909e-05
x before: -nan
x after: -nan
y before: -nan
y after: -nan
th before: nan
th after: nan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, your x and y "before" values are -nan. Adding anything to nan will still yield nan. If I had to guess, you are going through one loop iteration before your callbacks actually receive any data.

Also, consider this bit of code:

```
while(n.ok())
    {
        ros::spinOnce();               // check for incoming messages
        fr_enc = n.subscribe("front_encoders", 1, feCallBack);
        rr_enc = n.subscribe("rear_encoders", 1, reCallBack);
```

You are repeatedly subscribing to the topics for every loop iteration. Move lines 56 and 57 out of the while loop:

```
fr_enc = n.subscribe("front_encoders", 1, feCallBack);
rr_enc = n.subscribe("rear_encoders", 1, reCallBack);

while(n.ok())
    {
        ros::spinOnce();               // check for incoming messages
```

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2014-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2014-08-11**:
More or less what the guy in my lab did :P